# Predicting the next word using KerasNLP

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, tf.keras

I'm using `KerasNLP` to `generate` next sequence and `predicting` the next word. For that, I'm following [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/codelabs/blob/main/KerasNLP/io2023_workshop.ipynb). I'm getting trouble in converting the `logits` into `tokens` & `words`. So here is the summary of statements:

```
gpt2_tokenizer = keras_nlp.models.GPT2Tokenizer.from_preset("gpt2_base_en")
gpt2_preprocessor = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor.from_preset(
    "gpt2_base_en",
    sequence_length=256,
    add_end_token=True,
)
gpt2_lm = keras_nlp.models.GPT2CausalLM.from_preset("gpt2_base_en", preprocessor=gpt2_preprocessor)
```

To predict the next tokens:

```
output_tokens = keras_nlp.utils.top_k_search(
    gpt2_lm.predict,
    prompt.numpy(), <<<<<<========== This is where confusion is. How to give prompt
    max_length=4,
    k=50257,
    end_token_id=50256,
    from_logits=True
)
```

Currently, I'm using:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["Morning"])
preprocessed_ds = ds.map(gpt2_preprocessor)
output = next(iter(preprocessed_ds))
prompt = output[0]['token_ids']
```

If I use the above prompt, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'gpt2_tokenizer_3' (type GPT2Tokenizer).
        
        in user code:
        
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/tokenizers/tokenizer.py", line 138, in call  *
                return self._tokenize_without_call(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/tokenizers/byte_pair_tokenizer.py", line 471, in tokenize  *
                raw_tokens = split_strings_for_bpe(inputs)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras_nlp/tokenizers/byte_pair_tokenizer.py", line 97, in split_strings_for_bpe  *
                inputs = tf.strings.regex_replace(
        
            TypeError: Input 'input' of 'StaticRegexReplace' Op has type int32 that does not match expected type of string.
        
        
        Call arguments received by layer 'gpt2_tokenizer_3' (type GPT2Tokenizer):
          • args=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 255), dtype=int32)',)
          • mode=tokenize
          • training=None
          • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'gpt2_causal_lm_preprocessor_1' (type GPT2CausalLMPreprocessor):
      • x=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 255), dtype=int32)
      • y=None
      • sample_weight=None
```

Can someone please point out:

1. How to give prompt to `kerasnlp.utils.top_k_search`
2. What is the above error referring to? Any direction would be helpful.